# Capacitor Camera to not show prompt dialogue

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using the camera plugin from *Capacitor* with angular in order to save images locally from both desktop and tablet.
I want to be able to use the `CameraSource` to directly open the camera or open the file gallery and to **not show** the prompt.

My code looks like this:

My A.html

```
<button (click)="addPhoto('Camera')">Capture Image</button>
<button (click)="addPhoto('Photos')">Choose from Gallery</button>
```

A.ts

```
import { CameraDirection, CameraResultType, CameraSource, Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Camera } = Plugins;

async addPhoto(source) {
  if (source === 'Camera') {
      const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 90,
      source: CameraSource.Camera
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
    });
  } else if ( source === 'Photos') {
      const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 90,
      source: CameraSource.Photos
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
    });
  }
}
```

Somehow Capacitor ingores my source property.
Is my desired behaviour even possible?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: for source attribute a comma is required towards the end

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing a comma after the source parameter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to correct the syntax error.
Try the following snippet to fix the source of image input either device Gallery/Photos or directly for Camera input.

```
async openCamera(){
  const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
    quality: 90,
    allowEditing: true,
    source: CameraSource.Camera, //this should remove the prompt
    resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl
  });

  // image.webPath will contain a path that can be set as an image src.
  // You can access the original file using image.path, which can be
  // passed to the Filesystem API to read the raw data of the image,
  // if desired (or pass resultType: CameraResultType.Base64 to 
  //getPhoto)
  const imageUrl = image.webPath;
  this.image = image.dataUrl;
  // Can be set to the src of an image now
```

}